# Use Salesforce Campaigns to control Marketing Cloud Lists and Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud

Migrating from Pardot to Marketing Cloud.

In Pardot the Lists and Subscribers are very well and simply managed using:

Lists - Always visible in Pardot, can be made visible in Salesforce and also made public (made visible on the email preference page(s)). 
Email Preference page(s) - very easily styled to look exactly as required.

I can't seem to get a simple explanation of how to manage subscribers in Marketing Cloud.

Stack Exchange, please educate me!